# CSS: prevent child element with text content to grow window size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an element with long text content that I want to truncate/shrink when it is bigger than the parent's width. However instead of truncating/shrinking with "text..." style the whole window width grows and a horizontal schrollbar appears.
How can I fix this and generally how do I prevent a child element to increase the parent element's width? Note that the content element is within a flex item.

Example code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqMNXe:

HTML

```
<body>
  <nav>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <article>
        lorem ipsum dolores lorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum doloreslorem ipsum dolores
    </article>
  </main>
</body>
```

CSS

```
    body{
        display: flex;
        height: 100%;
    }

    html {
      height: 100%;
    }

    nav {
        background-color: aquamarine;
        width: 20em;

        flex-shrink: 0;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        border-right: 0.2em solid black;
    }

    main {
        background-color: bisque;
        flex-shrink: 1;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }

    article {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Thanks,
Z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove:

```
 white-space: nowrap;
```

from you article css class.

Or if you mean that you want to truncate your text. You will need a fixed width or if you want to do it with flexbox: [see this](https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/)

Comment: The solution given in the link namely "add `min-width: 0;` on the flex child" works nicely even if the long text content is deeper in the dom tree. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try giving width for nav and main percentage wise.

For example :

```
   nav {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    width: 30%;

    flex-shrink: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border-right: 0.2em solid black;
}

main {
    background-color: bisque;
    width: 70%;

}
```

Comment: This could solve this issue. The problem (a constraint) is that I need to size the nav based on em so that it depends on the font size. I may want the nav even more flexible and don't want to use fixed size at all.